# Git pre-commit hook fails running gradle command

Tags: git, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to run the following git pre-commit hook:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running git pre-commit hook"

# Format code using KtLint
./gradlew app:ktlintFormat app:ktlint --daemon --stacktrace

RESULT=$?

if [ "$RESULT" = 0 ] ; then
    echo "Ktlint found no problems."
    exit 0
else
    echo 1>&2 "Ktlint found violations it could not fix."
    exit 1
fi
```

But it keeps failing.
The problem appears to be my app build.gradle file where I use a [gladed/gradle-android-git-version gradle script](https://github.com/gladed/gradle-android-git-version) to apply version name and code.

Here's the stacktrace

```
Commit failed with error
0 files committed, 3 files failed to commit: Simplified examination dialog layout and usage.

Running git pre-commit hook
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/SmartGFR/app/build.gradle' line: 37

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Bare Repository has neither a working tree, nor an index

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
```

The exception points to the following line in my app build.gradle file:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionName androidGitVersion.name()
...
}
```

Anyone know how to fix  this?

Comment: Why are you using both `ktlintFormat` and `ktlint` in same command? I don't think that's valid.

Comment: @RahulBansal According to [this](https://proandroiddev.com/ooga-chaka-git-hooks-to-enforce-code-quality-11ce8d0d23cb) it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this locally @bohsen.

The steps:

1. Make the modification [https://github.com/gladed/gradle-android-git-version/issues/87#issue-731476471]
2. Generate a local jar
3. Import the jar and apply the plugin
4. Re-run the hook again

The issue:
https://github.com/gladed/gradle-android-git-version/issues/87